# RoR Hartl CH 7 bcrypt error when trying to load Users URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm at ch. 7 on the Hartl RoR tutorial.

When I try to load the url /users/1 it's supposed to give me the Example User (which I successfully updated in console.

Instead, I get this error screen:

```
    LoadError in UsersController#show
    cannot load such file -- bcrypt
        def require(file)
            result = false
            load_dependency(file) { result = super }
            result
          end
        end

Rails.root: /home/ubuntu/workspace
```

Not sure what this means exactly. I've gone through all my code so far from this chapter and last, and can't seem to find what I'm missing.

Any help is appreciated, and hopefully for any other newbie using this tutorial, as well.

Thanks,

Tim

Comment: Do you have bcrypt in your Gemfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if you have this in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby'
```

If not, add it. Then run `bundle install` to install it and don't forget to **restart the server**.

Tutorial says to install it `gem 'bcrypt', '3.1.7'` in chapter 6, but it doesn't say anything about restart the server. That's what you normally do after adding a gem.

**Listing 6.33: Adding bcrypt-ruby to the Gemfile.**

https://www.railstutorial.org/book/modeling_users

Comment: That was it! I had bcrypt in gemfile, and ran bundle install, just needed to restart server! Thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: FWIW, I had this problem following the tutorial.   Even though I had read that 'bcrypt-ruby' is deprecated and one should use just plain 'bcrypt' I could not get rid of this error until I put 'bcrypt-ruby' in my Gemfile:
`bundle install | grep bcry //
Using bcrypt 3.1.10 //
Using bcrypt-ruby 3.1.5 //`
I wonder if this is an error in the tutorial, but if it is, you'd think it would be a more common problem.